# Form Submit button doesnt work with PHP loop

Tags: php, forms, button, submit

I have this code

```
<tbody>
            <form action="dsf.php" method="post">
            <?PHP if(mysql_num_rows($leerdb) > 0) {while ($rs = mysql_fetch_row($leerdb)) {?>
                <tr>
                    <td><input name="idecod[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $rs[0]; ?>"  /></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rs[0]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rs[1]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rs[2]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rs[3]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rs[4]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rs[5]; ?></td>
                    <td>BsF. <?php echo $rs[6]; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?PHP }}?>
                <input class="enviar" type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="Editar Asesor" />
        </form>
             </tbody>
```

I do not know why the submit button doesnt work. When I click on it, nothing happend.

It seems that something in the php loop is making the mess.. But as I know, PHP goes first than HTML, so, when FORM HTML comes, PHP code was already executed.

Where is my error.??

Thanks in advance.

Roberto

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML?

Comment: Put your code in a local sample. It's working fine for me. -- But you shouldn't use the same name over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are generating invalid HTML.

You can't have a form wrapped around table rows without wrapping it around the entire table.

You can't have a submit button placed between table rows.

The browser you are using is likely trying to recover from the error in such a way that the form is moved somewhere where it is allowed, but where it doesn't contain any of the controls.

NB: Different browsers recover from having forms in inappropriate parts of tables in different ways.

[Use a validator](http://validator.w3.org/), and write real HTML.

Comment: Thanks.!! It works now... This may be a stupid question, but I thought there where no relation in the position of the HTML tags, as long as they have a proper start and ending.

Thanks again.!!

Answer (score -1):

instead of opening the brackets for the while and if, use the php short tags. Example:

```
    <?php if (condition): ?>
        output your html here
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Same thing goes for while. read about it here: www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Comment: You can nest as many whiles and ifs as you want, just make sure you close each one accordingly! It's easy to get lost. Cheers

Comment: While that could improve readability … how will that help solve this problem?